# Modifying httpd.conf to serve over the internet in EasyPHP

Tags: windows, apache, easyphp

I'm running EasyPHP on Windows. The default install just opens port 80 on the loopback interface, 127.0.0.1.  I want my sites to be accessible over the local network too. There are no simple EasyPHP settings for enabling my other interface, like the one that's connected to the internet (let's say 192.168.1.3). What do I add/modify in Apache httpd.conf?

Comment: What do you currently have in your httpd.conf?

Comment: the EasyPHP default configuration has some entries for localhost- 
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
ServerName 127.0.0.1:80
and no <VirtualHost> entries.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this software can you show me the httpd.conf?

Comment: Those two lines are really it, the rest is boilerplate. I just want to listen on my internet IP as well, but when I add the IP to the Listen directive, it opens the port but it serves a placeholder Apache page instead of serving from the right directory.

Comment: Do I have to define a VirtualHost for my internet IP? How do I make it behave the same way  as the default host?

Comment: On my httpd.conf I don't use the listen nor the NameVirtualHost, and it work on my local net work. Maybe that can work for you if you comment them or remove them

Comment: yes you will have to define one, see my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this code in your httpd.conf

```
ServerName localdomain

# env
SetEnv TMP "/tmp"
ServerAdmin admin@devserver
DocumentRoot "/var/www"

#NameVirtualHost *:80
#Listen 80

##################################################################
# default
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www"
  ServerName www.localdomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

** I just realize EasyPHP is for windows. You might use `c:/path/to/www instead` of `/var/www`

Comment: Thanks, I will try this as soon as I am able.

Answer (score 1):

I just need to add this line

```
Listen <your machine IP>:<your port>
```

e.g.

```
Listen 192.168.1.3:8080
```

and restart `Apache`