# How to make a server with old computer

Tags: apache, server, host, easyphp

I want to make a server on my old PC.I have easyphp 5.3 and open port is 8888.I can find my Wan IP.How to make a server that i can access to php and html files on www directory from other PC's?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7549382/3802077

Comment: my .con file don't contains these lines...

Answer (score 0):

EasyPHP includes Apache (a web server), mySQL (a database you can use with web applications) and PHP (a language you can use to program web applications).

So you've got a good start :)

SUGGESTION:

Work through a couple of tutorials:

- See if the EasyPHP web site has a tutorial.
- Or better, Google for *ANY* tutorial on "Apache, PHP and mySQL"
- There are also many books available.

ALSO:

To access your server by name, you'll need DNS.